# Fetch tag values for a measurement - influxDB

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I am trying to fetch the tag values for a given measurement.
i have my measurement in influxDB as given below.

```
> select * from "EVENT_LIVE"
name: EVENT_LIVE
time                GROUP_ID      COUNT
----                ------------- ---------
1531008000000000000 84            2
1531008000000000000 9             8
1532822400000000000 249           1
1534636800000000000 43            1
1534636800000000000 68            1
1535241600000000000 13            13
1535241600000000000 18            4
1535241600000000000 205           2
1535241600000000000 21            6
1535241600000000000 214           1
1535241600000000000 23            1
1535241600000000000 238           1
1535241600000000000 249           1
1535241600000000000 282           14
1535241600000000000 29            1
1535241600000000000 316           3
1535241600000000000 32            13
1535241600000000000 41            7
1535241600000000000 43            1
1535241600000000000 6             1
```

Here the name of the measurement is `EVENT_LIVE` and `GROUP_ID` is the tag and the `COUNT` is the value for the measurement.

i have executed the below influxDB query.

```
 > show tag values with key=GROUP_ID

    name: EVENT_LIVE
key           value
---           -----
GROUP_ID       13
GROUP_ID       18
GROUP_ID       204
GROUP_ID       206
GROUP_ID       21
GROUP_ID       217
GROUP_ID       22
GROUP_ID       238
GROUP_ID       245
GROUP_ID       249
GROUP_ID       25
GROUP_ID       259

name: EVENT_COMPLETED
key           value
---           -----
GROUP_ID       15
GROUP_ID       18
GROUP_ID       204
GROUP_ID       206
GROUP_ID       21
GROUP_ID       234
GROUP_ID       22
GROUP_ID       238
GROUP_ID       245
GROUP_ID       265
GROUP_ID       13
GROUP_ID       259
```

The tag values are retrieved for all the measurements in the database.

But when i tried to fetch the tags specific to the measurement

`EVENT_LIVE`, by executing the below query, i am not seeing any results.

what can be the issue with the below query ?

```
show tag values with key=GROUP_ID where "name" ='PGM_LIVE'
```

Comment: The influxDB version that i am using is `1.6.0`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Q:** Why is my query showing data from all measurements?

**A:** You'll have to be explicit. That is, you need to tell your query where to look for the things, otherwise it will try its best to find the data you want from all measurements.

To narrow down the search space to just a measurement, you can use the `from` clause. Basically just like what you did in your `SELECT` statement.

e.g. `show tag values from EVENT_LIVE with key=GROUP_ID;`

See https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/query_language/data_exploration/#from-clause

Answer (score 1):

Hi Siva following should work ..

show tag values from pgm_live with key=GROUP_ID

or

show tag values from event_live with key=GROUP_ID

best regards , Marc V. (Mata)